# read specific paragraph of html asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given below code is use for read paragraph from html page.Its good code but how can take one by one paragraph or if i have to save only paragraph 2 or 5 how can pick only specific no of paragraph.

```
public string GetParagraphs(string html, int numberOfParagraphs)
{
    const string paragraphSeparator = "</p>";
    var paragraphs = html.Split(new[] { paragraphSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return string.Join("", paragraphs.Take(numberOfParagraphs).Select(paragraph => paragraph + paragraphSeparator));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from this code being fundamentally broken (you can't just split on `</p>`, not all HTML you find out there is valid HTML), you seem to be just looking for the `Skip()` method:

```
public string GetParagraphs(string html, int startParagraph, int numberOfParagraphs)
{
    // ...

    var result = paragraphs.Skip(startParagraph)
                           .Take(numberOfParagraphs)
                           .Select(paragraph => paragraph + paragraphSeparator);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this properly, please use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack).
Once you have it, you go with something like:

```
      HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
      htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
      htmlDoc.Load(new StringReader(PageContent));
      if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
      {
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(XPath);
        // Work with nodes selected via XPath here
      }
```

The PageContent variable should contain the whole HTML content of the web page. The XPath variable is a simple XPath query, e.g. "//p" will give you all Paragraphs.